# Sharing attributes among objects that can be used in decorated methods

Tags: python, object, decorator, class-attributes

I have a group of objects which are instances of the same class. I would like them to share a common attribute.
Ok, I can simply define a class attribute:

```
MyClass():
    classattr = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.instattr = None
```

but, I want to make another group of objects using the same class with the common attribute set to something else than the first group.

I need this attribute within the class so I can decorate methods as properties, while still using that attribute within the property method.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Shouldn't this be `def __init__(self): self.instattr = None`?

Comment: Properties are just methods, really, so they have full access to the class and instance. Did you mean a more general decorator?

Comment: Subclassing, putting the class attributes in the subclasses?

Comment: @ Martijn, yes they have full access to the class/instance, so they can access the classattr. But if I want another group of the same objectsm but with a different 'shared attribute' then it won't work as changing `classattr` will change it for both groups of objects. Moving `classattr` out of the class will prevent decorators on the methods that use `classattr`...

Answer (score 1):

You could make the class attribute a *dictionary*; each 'group' of instances is given it's own key in that dictionary:

```
class MyClass():
    classattr_groups = {'group1': None, 'group2': None}
```

The whole object is still shared among instances, but you'd use one of the keys for one group of instances, another for a second group, etc.

Another approach is to subclass; give each group its own derived class and own class attribute:

```
class MyClass():
    classattr = None


class MyClassGroup1(MyClass):
    classattr = 'group1'


class MyClassGroup2(MyClass):
    classattr = 'group2'
```

Comment: The dictionary idea could be useful. The problem with the 2nd method is that it 'hard codes' the number of class groups that can be created. I'd like that dynamic (I'd like the user to define as many groups as they like/need, which is unknown). There is still the issue of dynamically creating keys for the dictionary, but that is probably easier to overcome...

Comment: Yes, for a dynamic number of groups, I'd go with the dictionary approach.